# The most efficient way to use mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysqli, innodb

I am searching for a efficient way to use PHP MySQL innoDB connection but not able to found conclusive information on the web.

As I know, persistent connection is much faster than non-persistent one,

we can set up the connection in following way:

```
$instance_mysqli = new mysqli('p:127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password', 'db');
```

However, from the official website, it said the default behavior is "reset" on reuse, which is slower. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

> The mysqli extension does this cleanup by automatically calling the
>   C-API function mysql_change_user(). The automatic cleanup feature has
>   advantages and disadvantages though. The advantage is that the
>   programmer no longer needs to worry about adding cleanup code, as it
>   is called automatically. However, the disadvantage is that the code
>   could potentially be a little slower, as the code to perform the
>   cleanup needs to run each time a connection is returned from the
>   connection pool.

So, there is no way to pass parameter to the above constructor to avoid "reset"? The only way is to recompile extension from source code as the document suggested?

And my anther question is... if mysqli is so smart that it can automatically reset connection by default, what is the point many people still use non-persistent connection, which is even slower.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the question. its not about creating a persistent connection but to avoid the implicit reset. So yeah, i think you have to recompile by defining `MYSQLI_NO_CHANGE_USER_ON_PCONNECT`

Comment: and I'm wondering if persistent connection have the implicit "reset", then we can use it as the same way as "non-persistent connection, right? There are many article on the web saying persistent connection introduce unexpected behavior and we should think carefully before using that, but the official document indicates the "reset" feature can actually fix those "unexpected behavior", so it's confusing

Answer (score 2):

The cost of a connection is quite small, whether it is persistent or not, whether there is cleanup or not.

Normally, one should acquire one connection at the beginning of the program, and keep it until the end.  (There are some exceptions.)

The only time a connection is really noticeable is if you acquire a connection before each and every SQL query.

Bottom line:  Worry about your indexes, system design, etc, not about acquiring the connection.